# PhpSpec testing service layers correctly

Tags: php, tdd, repository-pattern, behat, phpspec

The application has several services and some of the functionality overlaps multiple services. Since **[PhpSpec wraps objects](http://www.phpspec.net/en/stable/cookbook/wrapped-objects.html)** I am only able to test one service at a time.

### Background:

The **group service** can create groups like "Red cars", "Blue cars".
The **car service** can assign cars to groups.

**Group Service:**

```
function createGroup($name);
```

**Car Service:**

```
function assignCarToGroup($car, $group);
```

### Problem:

When I'm describing the *car service* within PhpSpec I want to make sure that it can check if a car has been successfully assigned to a group.

To do that, the *group needs to exist* prior to assigning the car to it.

### Questions:

I need to create the group before I run the file. This is where I face the problem.

Would I rely on the previous examples (of the GroupServiceSpec) to create the groups, I would make the test very brittle.

How can I test if the car has been assigned successfully just within the car service?

GroupService.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

class GroupService
{
    private $group_repository;

    public function __construct($group_repository)
    {
        $this->group_repository = $group_repository;
    }

    public function CreateGroupServiceCall($name)
    {
        return $this->group_repository->createGroup($name);
    }
}
```

GroupRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

class GroupRepository
{
    public function createGroup($name)
    {
        file_put_contents($name . '.db', '');

        return true;
    }
}
```

CarService.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

class CarService
{
    private $car_repository;

    public function __construct($car_repository)
    {
        $this->car_repository = $car_repository;
    }

    public function AssignCarToGroupServiceCall($car, $group_name)
    {
        return $this->car_repository->assignCarToGroup($car, $group_name);
    }
}
```

CarRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace app;

class CarRepository
{
    public function assignCarToGroup($car, $name)
    {
        $file_path = $name . '.db';

        if (file_exists($file_path) == true) {
            file_put_contents($file_path, $car);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the tests:

GroupServiceSpec.php

```
<?php

namespace spec\App;

use App\GroupRepository;
use App\GroupService;
use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Prophecy\Argument;

class GroupServiceSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{

    function let()
    {
        $group_repository = new GroupRepository();
        $this->beConstructedWith($group_repository);
    }

    function letGo()
    {
        # Clean up and remove all DB files
        array_map('unlink', glob(__DIR__ . "/../../*.db"));
    }

    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType(GroupService::class);
    }

    function it_can_create_a_group()
    {
        $this->CreateGroupServiceCall('New Group')->shouldBe(true);
    }

}
```

GroupRepositorySpec.php

```
<?php

namespace spec\App;

use App\GroupRepository;
use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Prophecy\Argument;

class GroupRepositorySpec extends ObjectBehavior
{

    function letGo()
    {
        # Clean up and remove all DB files
        array_map('unlink', glob(__DIR__ . "/../../*.db"));
    }

    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType(GroupRepository::class);
    }

    function it_can_create_group()
    {
        $status = $this->createGroup('test');
        $status->shouldBe(true);
    }
}
```

CarServiceSpec.php

```
<?php

namespace spec\App;

use App\CarRepository;
use App\CarService;
use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Prophecy\Argument;

class CarServiceSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{

    function let()
    {
        $car_repository = new CarRepository();
        $this->beConstructedWith($car_repository);
    }

    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType(CarService::class);
    }

    function it_can_assign_car_to_group()
    {
        $car = 'Car I';
        $group_name = 'Group1';

        $this->AssignCarToGroupServiceCall($car, $group_name)->shouldBe(true);
    }
}
```

CarRepositorySpec.php

```
<?php

namespace spec\App;

use app\CarRepository;
use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Prophecy\Argument;

class CarRepositorySpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType(CarRepository::class);
    }

    function it_can_assign_car_to_group()
    {
        # how can I test this part, as the group is not existing now.
        # If I'm not to create the group, how can I test if this code works at all?
        # Do I have a design error?

        $car = 'Car1';
        $group_name = 'Company';

        $this->assignCarToGroup($car, $group_name)->shouldBe(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might be using the wrong tool for your use case. Phpspec is for unit testing, so If you're specing Car Service, you probably have to stub Group Service. If you want to test the integration between both, then use Behat.

Comment: Hello @gvf thank you very much. I'm actually using Behat as well for that. However I also want to make sure that this specific function is working on the unit test level. I think mocking it wouldn't be enough as there are real entries required. Would you leave it without a unit test or what would be your solution if you want to test it at the unit test level as well?

Comment: Unit level testing tests a class in isolation, you want to test the interaction between 2 classes, so what I would do is move the test to Behat. If you post the full code of both classes I might be able to assist you further.

Comment: @gvf here is the quick implementation of the code I've written: https://ufile.io/i4rt9 I'm also adding it to the question

Comment: Ok, first of all, never call a class '*Service.php` :-) it's too vague and then what will happen if you have more than one service? In your case, in CarServiceSpec you can only spec the behaviour: you can only spec that the call to `car_repository->assignCarToGroup` has been made, nothing else.

Comment: @gvf thank you, I think this is the answer I was looking for :) What should I call it instead? Do you have a recommendation how I could get better with this one? Thank you!

Comment: ServiceCallCarAssigner? I’m terrible at naming:-)

Comment: @gvf I usually put the most vital and related things inside so that's why I call them services :/ but I do get the point, and I'm really grateful :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your car service spec should look like:

```
class CarServiceSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{

  function let(CarRepository $carRepository)
  {
    $this->beConstructedWith($carRepository);
  }

  function it_is_initializable()
  {
    $this->shouldHaveType(CarService::class);
  }

  function it_can_assign_car_to_group(CarRepository $carRepository)
  {
    $car = 'Car I';
    $group_name = 'Group1';

    $carRepository->assignCarToGroup($car, $group_name)->shouldBeCalled()->willReturn(true);

    $this->AssignCarToGroupServiceCall($car, $group_name)->shouldReturn(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you @gvf after this part, should I consider it as "validated" even though I know the result is not there? Can I say, "My focus is on the part, if the correct method has been called or not?" Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what you can do. If you want to be sure it's persisted in DB, then go for a Behat test.

Comment: thank you very much! The whole thing also has behat on top of it as well, I just wanted to make sure. Thank you!!